# Gutenberg block in theme : integrate your own block initially as a plugin to a theme and error peticion

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I created a block initially as a plugin with the latest wordpress block.json architecture that worked and appeared within gutenberg but when integrating it to the theme I get an error of the url request error.

```
add_action('init', 'register_my_block');
function register_my_block(){
    register_block_type(
        __DIR__. '/myblocks', 
        array(        
            'render_callback' => 'render_my_block_posts'
    ));
}
```

Also use  `register_block_type_from_metadata()`  but got the same error

Example error in console:

```
https://domain.local/wp-content/plugins/D:/xampp/htdocs/wp-content/themes/NewsPaper/inc/gutenberg/myblocks/index.js?ver=d395fe5d9d90bd6565685c91d8d38888
```

A correct call is made to the php file of the functions to the file but when registering the request it goes wrong for the block

The code from block.json

```
{
    "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/block.json",
    "apiVersion": 2,
    "name": "block/custompost",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "title": "CustomPosts",
    "category": "widget",
    "icon": "grid-view",
    "description": "Display a custom post.",
    "keywords": [ "grid" , "gridview" , "custompost" ],
    "textdomain": "default",
    "attributes": {
        "columns": {
            "type": "number",
            "default": 3
        },
        "rows": {
            "type": "number",
            "default": 9
        },
        "display": {
            "type": "string",
            "default": ""
        },
        "display_setting": {
            "type": "array",
            "default": []
        "edit_mode": {
            "type": "boolean",
            "default": true
        }
    },
    "supports": {
        "align": [ "wide" , "full"],
        "html": false
    },

    "editorScript": "file:./index.js",
    "editorStyle": "file:./custompost.css"
}
```

Comment: could you please post the content of your JSON file inside the `myblocks` directory? this definitely seems to be some path problem.

Comment: the block.json file has already been added

Comment: something must be wrong when you enqueue your script, please take a look at this (similar) question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/354970/why-does-plugin-url-append-absolute-file-path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same issue, it appears to be this function is not available for themes in version Wordpress 5.9. I have just tested this exactly as is with Worpress 6.0 and it works as expected.

In prior version of wordpress it is purely for plugins, hence why it is looking at wp-content/plugins and then appending the url/path

Answer (score 0):

In the console error, the directory is "myblock" where as in the `register_block_type(...)` its "myblock**s**" (with a **s**). Potentially your issue is due to a small typo causing index.js to not be found.

Comment: Is there an example error but it doesn't reflect, the problem because the request calls file plugins and then filer for the theme